# Can't compile C code on Windows 10, to use it as Python module

Tags: python, c, windows

I tried some python modules and they did not satisfyed me.
So I decided now to create my own little module to track KeyBoardInput with the help of `c`.
On Linux everything works fine but on `Windows` the oder hand i have problems compiling the Code. I am using `Python 3.11.1` and `Windows 10`.

I get this Error Message:

```
gcc -shared -o custom_keyboard.pyd -I "C:/Program Files/Python311/include" -L"C:/Program Files/Python311/libs" -lpython311 custom_keyboard.c
In file included from C:/Program Files/Python311/include/Python.h:86:0,
                 from custom_keyboard.c:1:
C:/Program Files/Python311/include/cpython/pytime.h:184:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:/Program Files/Python311/include/cpython/pytime.h:190:12: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct timeval *tv,
            ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\MUDDYB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVKY98K.o:custom_keyboard.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
C:\Users\MUDDYB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVKY98K.o:custom_keyboard.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
C:\Users\MUDDYB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccVKY98K.o:custom_keyboard.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_Create2'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I used this piece of code:

```c
#include <Python.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
// Windows specific includes
#include <conio.h>
#else
// Unix specific includes
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

static PyObject *read_key(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ""))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    // Windows implementation
    int key = 0;
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        key = _getch();
    }
#else
    // Unix implementation
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);
    new_tio = old_tio;
    new_tio.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);

    int key = 0;
    char buf = 0;
    ssize_t n;
    if ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf, 1)) > 0)
    {
        key = buf;
    }

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_tio);
#endif

    return Py_BuildValue("i", key);
}

static PyMethodDef keyboardMethods[] = {
    {"read_key", read_key, METH_VARARGS, "Reads a single key from the keyboard."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}};

static struct PyModuleDef keyboardModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "keyboard",
    NULL,
    -1,
    keyboardMethods};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_custom_keyboard(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&keyboardModule);
}
```

So I found this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168842/issues-compiling-c-code-for-a-python-module) but changing `PyInit_custom_keyboard` to `Pycustom_keyboard_Create` Didn't help.

Using the Developer Shell of Visual Studio with:

```
cl /LD /I"C:\Program Files\Python311\include" custom_keyboard.c /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Python311\libs" /OUT:custom_keyboard.pyd
```

I get this Error.
I can compile it with Python-32bit but not with the 64 bit version why?

```
C:\Program Files\Python311\libs\python311.lib: Warning LNK4272:Library computer type "x64" conflicts with target computer type "x86"
custom_keyboard.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Comment: FWIW, `kbhit` and `getch` [are already in the built-in `msvcrt` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o).

Comment: Anyway, you'll probably need to compile your module with MSVC on Windows.

Comment: Yeah damn You are right. But I have th feeling it is kind of faster with c... So it was on Linux.
But also In VS I get an error

Comment: Well, evidently you're trying to compile as 32-bit, not 64-bit.

Comment: Yeah I installed 32bit Python now it did work. tho why ist it not working with the gcc command?

Comment: But the C code is pretty slow. Like the real modules in python... When you hit a key for a longer period it still returns that input some seconds after you pulled the key

Comment: Nevermind :D only in VSCODE console in the real python console it is as good as on linux now :)
Thank your for the tipp with MSVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well on windows use the Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

- To create a `32_bit` version use the `x86 native tools command promt`
- To create a `64_bit` version use the `x64 native tools command promt`

Don't forget to add the Path to the correct Architecture Python-folder